# How do I set Ruby Sequel logging to the DEBUG level?

Tags: ruby, logging, sequel

The default Ruby Sequel behaviour is to log all DB queries at the INFO level (unlike ActiveRecord which logs at the DEBUG level). How do I change this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Previously, it was fairly simple to do with a proxy logger object, but enough people have asked for this that I implemented it.  With the git master branch of Sequel, you can now do:

```
DB.sql_log_level = :debug
```

Which will use the debug method instead of the info method when logging queries.

Comment: Probably in an initializer.  It does depend on the Sequel::Database object being in DB, which may not be true if you are not loading it yourself.  A safer bet is:Sequel::DATABASES.each{|d| d.sql_log_level = :debug}

Comment: Hi Jeremy, that answer was from 2010. I just tried it (`DB.sql_log_level = :debug`) and no debugging output at all. What is the currently working method? (Would be especially nice to see that here, since this is the first hit on Google...)

Comment: @Sixtyfive Make sure you supply a logger to the database:

`require 'sequel'; require 'logger'; DB = Sequel.sqlite; DB.loggers << Logger.new($stdout); DB['select 1'].to_a` => `I, [2020-07-03T18:28:33.321470 #262544]  INFO -- : (0.000376s) select 1`